# Using Bridget.NET with Angular2

Tags: angular, bridge.net

I am interested in Bridge.NET but I would like to use it for Angular2 Apps.

Currently I find it difficult because Angular2 uses Typescript. Have anyone seen any attempts to integrated it with Angular2-4?

Answer (score 1):

Check out using Retyped for integrating Angular support with a Bridge project.

https://retyped.com/?q=angular#search

Comment: Wow that site looks great. I found many resources for AngularJS but not for Angular 4